# how to show popup every 3rd time app has launched?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I need to show a popup every 3rd time my app has lunached.

I am using `Appirater` also for rating my app.Will it be ok if i append code in that to get my task done? 
or is there any other way to acknowledge launching of my app every 3rd time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can store in NSUserDefault for the App launch count and can show the alert every third time app launching.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if(![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"firstTime"] isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Yes" forKey:@"firstTime"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ApplaunchCount"] + 1) forKey:@"ApplaunchCount"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ApplaunchCount"] + 1) forKey:@"ApplaunchCount"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ApplaunchCount"] % 3 ==0)
        {
            UIAlertView *lanuchAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Message Title" message:@"Your Message Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [lanuchAlert show];
            [lanuchAlert release];
        }
    }

    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: it works fine.but how can i reset it after 3rd time it has been shown?

Comment: You just want to show for 3rd time. I thought you want to show for every 3rd time. Here you can set it to one more UserDefaulut when you get for the first time alert and set it TRUE and from next time if it is TRUE then no need to show alert. Let me know if any issue.

Comment: i didn't noticed `%3==0` that will work for every 3rd time.your code is working fine.thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust `LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT` in "Appirater.h". Or you can use userDefaults.

Comment: i tried it out but it makes so much confusion so i thought not to edit that and try something else

Comment: Then [userDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about *Appirater*, but you can use **NSUserDefaults** and a simple logic to achieve this. Set an **NSNumber** value to user defaults and increment it every time the app loads. Initially the number will be *nil* when you try to access it using the key. If it is *nil* set *1* as the value, and increment it every time the app loads. If the number becomes 3, show the pop-up and reset the number to 0.